# OS Booting Issue

Tags: operating-system

Because my work will get lighter for the next month or so, I decided to mess around with OS's, just to see how they work. I found [this website](http://mikeos.berlios.de/write-your-own-os.html), and I'm trying to run the code he provided. I am following the instructions exactly (to the best of my ability), but when I go to try booting with QEMU, I get this text:

```
SeaBios (version-blahblah)

Booting from Hard Disk...
Boot failed: could not read the boot disk.

Booting from Floppy...
```

And it never actually boots. I am relatively new to Ubuntu, and hoping that somebody would be able to point me towards where I made a mistake. I hope this is enough information to diagnose my error, and thanks in advance!

EDIT: Alright, I tried another tutorial which took me through very similar steps (but with slightly different code), and I still had the same issue. I also booted MikeOS from the floppy image it comes with, and it worked fine.

EDIT 2: Aaaaah! I just realized that when I pressed Ctrl+C, the text that was supposed to appear appeared for just a moment, then went away, along with QEMU. What can I do to make the text appear sooner? I've tried moving the infinite loop to after the display command, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I want to start by saying that I didn't read the entire page you provided (as I don't have enough time). However, the error that you cannot boot from HDD, regardless of the OS, usually (always in my previous experiences) means that either the MBA (Master Boot Record) is messed up/incorrect or you don't have a partition with a boot flag on it.

When I have some time I'll look deeper into that page and see if i can find exactly what the problem could be.

Comment: I wasn't able to fix it. I edited my post to provide more information as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the bytes 0x55, 0xAA at offset 510 of your MBR?